# Is it possible to restrict Windows Explorer operations from navigation pane (especially delete, copy)

Tags: windows-explorer

I work with remote machines a lot. As I flick back and forth between local and remote systems, Windows Explorer often tricks me into doing operations with a far larger scope than intended. For example:

1. Select a certain file deep in the C: drive on one system
2. Switch to other system to compare file details (date, version, whatever)
3. Return to first system to perform operation (e.g. copy, delete) on selected file
4. Windows navigation pane shows c: drive highlighted; selected file also seems to be highlighted; nonetheless, operation is applied to entire C: drive!!!

This is super annoying... not to mention potentially catastrophic. Perhaps it is related to the way I access remote machines (LogMeIn). Either way, I don't want to change that - I want to change the behaviour of Windows Explorer.

Is there are way to tell Windows Explorer I NEVER want to perform operations like this from the navigation pane, and ONLY on the selected file (if any) in the file list? If this is not possible, is there any other mechanism I can use so that my rapid typing of SHIFT+DELETE then ENTER to OK the "are you sure?" popup doesn't start permanently deleting my life's work?

Answer (score 0):

I did some looking. There is no way to control Windows Explorer,xPlorer2, or Total Commander key activities. (I have and use all the above).

Further, I assume you are probably working as Administrator on your own and perhaps some of the remoter machines. Administrator has complete control which further amplifies the above statement and complicates the issue.

For some operations, you may find Command line processing operations helpful as a number include "Are you sure?" messages.

So I think you have to do what the rest of us doing this kind of work and that is to work deliberately and carefully to avoid mistakes.

Comment: I suspected as much :-( I am used to working rapidly and by touch typing and (over-)familiarity. Old habits typically die hard... but watching Windows prepare to delete everything on my C: drive was a sobering wake-up call!

Comment: What I posted is the way things work. Make sure you watch "are you sure you want to Delete or like messages" . A number of these messages occur in Windows Apps. Also command line file operations include "are you sure"